# python-2.5, "argument must be dict, not dict"

Tags: python-2.5

Python 2.5 expects a dict, not a dict?

```
# python --version
Python 2.5.5
```

Opensolaris derivate (NexentaStor), trying to add zfs permissions but this strange error prevents me.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/zfs/dataset.py", line 203, in set_fsacl
  return zfs.ioctl.set_fsacl(self.name, un, d)
TypeError: argument 3 must be dict, not dict
```

Here's the block of code in question, I added some printing to see types and such:

```
    def set_fsacl(self, un, d):
            """Add to the "zfs allow"-ed permissions on this Dataset.

            un is True if the specified permissions should be removed.

            d is a dict specifying which permissions to add/remove:
            { "whostr" -> None # remove all perms for this entity
              "whostr" -> { "perm" -> None} # add/remove these perms
            } """

            print self.name
            print un
            print d
            print type(d)
            return zfs.ioctl.set_fsacl(self.name, un, d)
```

My print statements gives the following output:

```
tank/xenserver_vol1  <-- self.name
False  <-- un
{'ud$1001': {'send': None}, 'ul$1001': {'send': None}}  <-- d
<type 'dict'>  <-- type(d)
```